# how install XBMC – Kodi Media Center media player on ubuntu?

Tags: xbmc

how install XBMC–Kodi Media Center media player on Ubuntu,using terminal.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

All the info you need can be found at https://kodi.tv